# Google Analytics UAT on another domain

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-filters

It seems that a company from Korea downloaded our front-end html/CSS files and built a website, but they did not bother to remove our UAT number and now our analytics are full of misleading traffic from their website. Already contacted them to remove it but is there a way to exclude entirely the data from that domain?

Answer (score 1):

At view level, you can use a custom filter to block it. You've got a few pre-set options on what to block - by hostname or by country, or an entirely custom definition. This won't back-date, a segment with the same sort of filters will do it for existing data.

Answer (score 1):

A hostname filter is probably the best if it is a single website that has copied your code. As mentioned above, it will not back-date